# Custom Parameters in a Manual Test Case

Tags: testing, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I have a question regarding a manual Test Case in Microsoft Test Manager. Is there a way to define 'custom' parameters?

Normally, you can define whatever parameter you want, like @FirstName. This parameter will automatically be added to the list of parameters of your testcase.

But I was wondering if there is something like '@Date'.. which replaces itself in a -DateTime.Now- equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately that is not supported out of the box. The parameter parser does not understand special parameters. So, @date will not give you DateTime.Now

You can however, convert the test to a coded UI test and overwrite the parameter value to pass DateTime.Now when @date is passed.

However, i like your suggestion and would recommend that you raise it on the user voice site here => http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio